# how to receive the most commented posts without duplicating in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I've been trying on solving this issue and couldn't. 
I'm making a blog web app using ASP.net MVC, and trying to create a top stories based on comments count.
This query below:

```
        var top = (from p in posts
                    join c in comments
                    on p.Id equals c.whichPost
                   orderby posts.Where(h=>h.Id==c.whichPost).Count()  
                   select(p)
                    ).Take(5);
```

My View:

```
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="/Posts/Detail/@item.Id">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem      => item.Title)</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

}

Is actually querying the top ones but, in view it prints the name of title according to the comments' count. What I'm trying to say:

- Title 1 (i.e it has 4 comments)
- Title 1
- Title 1
- Title 1
- title 3 (2 comments)
- title 3
- Title 2 (one comment)

Any hints on solving this issue?
 Thanks.

Comment: How about `Distinct()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [group join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534805%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
 var top = (from p in posts
            join c in comments on p.Id equals c.whichPost into g
            orderby g.Count() descending // don't forget to use descending order
            select p).Take(5);
```

Or if you have navigation properties in your entities

```
 var top = posts.OrderByDescending(p => p.Comments.Count()).Take(5);
```

Note: your current code creates a post-comment pair for each comment which matches some post. That's why you see duplications. Also there is issue with posts which don't have comments. Simple join will not give you any matches.